# Only safe or non-null asserted calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I have data class for my api response as below

```
data class ApiResponse(
@SerializedName("ErrorCode") @Expose
var errorCode: Int = 0,
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
var message: String? = null,

@SerializedName("Token")
@Expose
var token: String? = null,

@SerializedName("UserId")
@Expose
var userId: String? = null,

@SerializedName("DOB")
@Expose
var birthdate: String? = null,

@SerializedName("Mobile")
@Expose
var mobile: String? = null,

@SerializedName("Data")
@Expose
var dataList: MutableList<Data?>? = null
)
```

My api call

```
val request = ApiServiceBuilder.buildService(NetworkCall::class.java)
    request.login(apiPost = ApiPost("long","hello")).enqueue(object :Callback<ApiResponse>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ApiResponse>, response: Response<ApiResponse>) {
            Log.e("resopne",response.body().userId)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ApiResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            t.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("resopne","error")
        }
    })
```

While try to get userId I get

Only safe  or non-null asserted  calls are allowed on a nullable

Comment: Your data class variable `var userId: String? = null` is nullable. You cannot directly call `response.body().userId`, add !! to the end `response.body().userId!!` but this will cause a nullPointerException if the  userId value is null. Refer https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `userId` in your model class as `optional or nullable` by putting a `?` in the front of the type.

```
@SerializedName("UserId")
@Expose
var userId: String? = null
```

So when reading a value from the `response.body()` it's telling you that the value `userId` inside your `response.body()` could be null and will throw a `null-pointer exception` in runtime. So, to protect it it is giving you two options:

1) `Only safe` `userId?` ->
This means that if the value is null then it will not continue execution of that particular line.

2) `Non-null asserted` `userId!!` ->
Means you are telling the compiler that it will never be null and you guarantee that so if by any chance this value gets null then it's gonna throw a runtime `null-pointer exception`.

So, best practices are you put a `?` for `Only Safe` and use it that way because it's not gonna make any difference if it is `not-null` always.